# Real analysis: Continuity and Differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Let $f(x)=x^2$ if $x$ is rational and $f(x)=0$ if $x$ is irrational.

a) Prove that f is continuous at exactly one point, namely $x=0$.

b) Prove that f is differentiable at exactly one point, namely $x=0$.

How can I show that $f$ is discontinuous and not differentiable for $x\neq 0$ ?

Comment: Use the definitions of continuous and differentiable.

Comment: update your question with the definition of continuity $f$ is *continuous* at $x$ if for each $\epsilon$ there exists a $\delta$... Then, negate it to see what happens when $f$ is *discountinuous* at $x$ -- namely, there is an $\epsilon$ such that for all $\delta$....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Let $a\in\mathbb R\backslash \{0\}$. Take a sequence $(a_n)\subset \mathbb R\backslash \mathbb Q$ and $(b_n)\subset \mathbb Q$ that both converge to $a$. Then, what are $$\lim_{n\to\infty }f(a_n)\quad \text{and}\quad \lim_{n\to \infty }f(b_n)\ \ ?$$

For the non differentiability, remember that a differentiable function is continuous.

Comment: Is $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(a_{n})=f(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_{n})$?

Comment: what do you think ? What is $f(a_n)$ and what is $f(\lim_{n\to \infty }a_n)$

Answer (score 1):

Generally, for function $f(x)=g(x)$ if $x$ is rational, and $f(x)=h(x)$ if $x$ is irrational, we have the followings

(1) $f$ is continuous only in the points that $g(x)=h(x)$.

(2) $f$ is differentiable in the points that $g'(x)=h'(x)$.

To show that $f$ is not continuous in the other points, it is enough to consider two sequences of rational and irrational numbers converging to the point you have considered.